# Opening Balances functions returns (Blank) - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

All opening balances (Month, Quarter & Year) functions return (Blank) BUT:

- All other Time intelligence functions such as MTD, QTD, YTD & PY work
  fine.
- Date column in dimension & fact tables are type: Date
- Time dimension includes all dates

**Time table & Time hierarchy structure:**

[image]

[image]

**Matrix visual:**

[image]

**Calculations:**

- OB Month = OPENINGBALANCEMONTH(SUM(FctTransactions[Units Sold]),DimTime[Date])
- OB Quarter = OPENINGBALANCEQUARTER(SUM(FctTransactions[Units Sold]),DimTime[Date])
- OB Year = OPENINGBALANCEYEAR(SUM(FctTransactions[Units Sold]),DimTime[Date])

Any idea what I m missing? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**------------------------------UPDATE------------------------------**

After @Sam Nseir comment and a deeper reading on time functions find below my findings:

- OP Monthly: Get the last date of the previous month. For example, if you select any date in December, you will get the value of 30th of November.
- OP Quarter: Get the last date of the previous quarter. For example, if you select any date in Q4 (October, November, and December), you will get the value of the last date of Q3 – 30th of September
- OP Year: Get the last date of the previous year. For example, if you select any date in year 2023, you will get the value of the last date of 2022 – 31st of December

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening Balance functions are designed for things like inventory, where you have continuous running dates of inventory. Not designed for transactions.

Opening Balance functions actually return the day before that period starts.
`OPENINGBALANCEMONTH(...)` is the same as `PREVIOUSDAY(STARTOFMONTH(...))`. So in your case it is getting the sum of the last day of the previous month, and I'm guessing you don't have any transactions then.

I think what you are after is the Previous Functions:

```
OB Month = PREVIOUSMONTH( SUM(FctTransactions[Units Sold]),DimTime[Date] )
OB Quarter = PREVIOUSQUARTER( SUM(FctTransactions[Units Sold]),DimTime[Date] )
OB Year = PREVIOUSYEAR( SUM(FctTransactions[Units Sold]),DimTime[Date] )
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. As you can see from the images i m using Units CY measure which depict the inventory. Also using OPENINGBALANCEMONTH for the any date in December 2023 i should get the value for November 2023. I manage to get those number using Date column from the table where Units CY comes from but i dont manage to get the numbers using the Date from Time table

Comment: But that is the problem, any date in December 2023 will give 30 November 2023, not all of November. As you don't have an entry for that one day, you are getting blank.